# Timeout para OracleConnection

Tags: oracle, vb.net

Tenho uma função para abrir a conexão dos bancos em Oracle e nessa função quero colocar um limite de tempo para a tentativa de se conectar ao banco.

Tentei usar `ConnectionString` desta maneira

```
oConexao.ConnectionString = "Data Source = MeuBd; User Id = MeuID; Password = 88997k21; Connection Timeout = 10;"
```

Porém não funcionou, caindo em uma Exception e acusando que não há suporte para a palavra-chave: 'connectiontimeout'.

Função:

```
Private Shared Function AbrirConexaoOracle(ByVal sNomeBanco As String, Optional ByRef mensagem As String = "") As OracleClient.OracleConnection

        Dim oConexao As OracleClient.OracleConnection

        Try
            oConexao = New OracleClient.OracleConnection
            If sNomeBanco = "OUTROS" Then
                oConexao.ConnectionString = mensagem
                mensagem = String.Empty
            Else
                oConexao.ConnectionString = LerConnectionString(sNomeBanco) 'MontarConnectionString(sNomeBanco)
            End If                
            oConexao.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            mensagem = ex.Message.ToString
            If Not oConexao Is Nothing Then
                oConexao.Close()
                oConexao.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
        Return oConexao

    End Function
```

De que forma posso dar esse limite para a tentativa de conexão no caso do uso de `OracleConnection` ?

Comment: Usando `Connection Timeout=XX;` na tua `ConnectionString` deveria funcionar! Podes colocar o erro que estás a receber? (o erro original e não uma tradução e/ou descrição do mesmo)

Comment: A mensagem é essa mesmo, Não há suporte para a palavra-chave: 'connection timeout'. Assim que ele cai na linha `oConexao.ConnectionString = "Data Source = MeuBd; User Id = MeuID; Password = 88997k21; Connection Timeout = 10;"` vai direto para o Exception e retorna o erro.

Comment: Qual o provedor de dados que estás a utilizar (SQL Server, OLE DB, ODBC, outro...) ?

Comment: Utilizo o OLE DB.